# Storing history of entries in Solidity smart contract

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I'am learning writing Solidity smart contract and I need to save some data on blockchain. What I want to get is history of user's grades entries.

Desired result:

Input:

```
setUserDetails('XYZ', 5)
setUserDetails('XYZ', 3)
```

Output:

```
getUserGrades('XYZ')

Grade 5 added for XYZ on 01/01/22 12:00
Grade 3 added for XYZ on 01/01/22 12:01
```

Previously I was planning to fetch history based on events, but I found out that specific block numbers are needed to get to events. Even if I store the block number in a struct, each subsequent "add" of the mark will result in an overwrite, and the get getUserGrades method will only return the most recent record. What solidity capabilities are best to use in this case?

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Users {

    struct User {
        string username;
        uint grade;
    }

    mapping(string => User) userMap;

    event userDetailsChanged(
        string username,
        uint grade
    );

    function setUserDetails(string memory _username, uint _grade) external {

        userMap[_username].username = _username;
        userMap[_username].grade = _grade;

        emit userDetailsChanged(_username, _grade);
    }

    function getUserGrades(string memory _username) external view returns(uint _grade) {
        return (
            userMap[_username].grade
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by history? you could just add timetamp to the struct?

Comment: @Yilmaz Of course I can add a timestamp to the struct, but how to get the effect of registering a grade for a user with a unique timestamp? Please check the input and output for exactly what I mean. I need to know what grade was added for a user at a specific time.

Comment: when you calll `getUserGrades('XYZ')`, you want to get specifically this format: `Grade 5 added for XYZ on 01/01/22 12:00`. Am I correct?

Comment: Basically, I'm interested in when and for whom a given grade was added. The format in which the data will be returned is less importance, because I can format it on the JavaScript side. I allow multiple grades added for a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

```
contract Users {
    struct User {
        string username;
        uint[] grades;
        address byWhom;
        uint timestamp;
    }
    mapping(string => User) userMap;

    event userDetailsChanged(
        string username,
        uint grade
    );
    function setUserDetails(string memory _username, uint _grade) external {
        // if _username exists add your logic 
        // i cannot just write this: userMap[_username]. it cannot be convertible bool because if it does not exists, evm will return struct with default values
        if(userMap[_username].grades.length==0){
            User storage currentUser=userMap[_username];
            currentUser.grades.push(_grade);
            return;
        } 
        userMap[_username].username = _username;
        userMap[_username].grades.push(_grade);
        // you might need to add restriction rule to allow certain people to call this function.
        // msg.sender is the caller of this function
        userMap[_username].byWhom=msg.sender;
        userMap[_username].timestamp=block.timestamp;
        

        // YOU COULD ALSO DO THIS 
        // userMap[_username]=User(
        //     _username,
        //     _grade,
        //     msg.sender,
        //     block.timestamp
        // )
        emit userDetailsChanged(_username, _grade);
    }

    function getUserGrades(string memory _username) external view returns(uint[] memory _grades) {
        return (
            userMap[_username].grades
        );
    }
}
```

proof of work:

[image]

Comment: Adding timestamp and msg.sender doesn't solve problem of getting multiple grades for same user. The current struct will always contain only the most recent grade and timestamp.

Comment: @Wojtek correct. i did not understand the problem fully. updated

Comment: So I need to add just an array. Thank you, it looks understandable. I'm just asking to be sure. Will basing the history on events in this case and keeping the block numbers in the array in the struct, which will then be used to easily find events by queryFilter function of ethers.js, will be a correct approach?

Comment: since you have block.timestamp, you can also get the date from that time. ethereum timestamp is in seconds since the epoch. try to use either one. you do not need to implement two things for one thing. always remember anything you do costs you. events are cheper.

Comment: Ok I just want to avoid operations on multidimension arrays, because I need pairs of grades and timestamps. I think that storing block numbers in struct and then getting whole events with such data using block numbers will simply give me an easy access to this kind of informations.